# Using all methods mentioned on StackOverflow, I cannot get bs4 to import in pyCharm. How can I get it?

Tags: python, pycharm

Importing bs4 doesn't work, pip install bs4 doesn't solve the problem in pyCharm (even when using pyCharm's internal console). It will install, but doesn't permit code using "bs4" to go through.

I've never had any issue with another package, but it seems like pyCharm is fundamentally incompatible with BeautifulSoup. Has anyone ever gotten it to work?

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Example code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

With the same exact code, I'm watching a person on YouTube get no errors. So, I'm doing something silly over here.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @DARK_C0D3R I've edited my original comment to show that the error is: oduleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: Python modules are independent of what you use to write code (which is just text). If you edit your answer to show the commands (and include where you typed the commands) that you've used in addition to the error you got we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @Jason Edited to show code.

Comment: To install `bs4` where did you type the `pip install bs4` command?

Comment: Does it run outside pyCharm? Cause pyCharm is definitely NOT incompatible with bs, i've just tested an totally ancient version of pyCharm i had laying around, set a breakpoint, and stepped into bs's findall function... if it doesn't run without pyCharm - well, fix that. If it actually runs normally (outside pyCharm) - find what python directory pyCharm uses. My bet is you have more than one.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Yep, runs perfectly fine. I was messing with a completely different program exclusively in the Windows/Python console and everything was fine. Same with this one. All of these have been tests

Comment: @Jason Originally just in the windows terminal, then in pyCharm's native console, then in the actual text editor (didn't assume that'd do anything, but was out of ideas, so I tried that).

Comment: I am not a pyCharm guru, but i'd bet on a pyCharm having some config for where the python it uses resides. And you probably have it set to some kind of ancient copy coming from god knows where.

Comment: Are you using PyCharm to create a virtual environment for your project (the default behaviour)? If so, installing in the Windows console will install `bs4`for your system's Python and not for you Pycharm project. Can you try clicking on the 'terminal' tab of Pycharm, then running `pip install bs4`, if there are no errors type `python` and once the python prompt appears try `import bs4`. If there's an error at any stage please let me know what it was.

Comment: @Jason So, I did all of that and everything was fine (the Terminal recognized that bs4 had already been installed, understood me when I typed in Python, and gave no errors when I imported bs4). But, when running the program, it still doesn't recognize bs4 . "No Module named bs4."

Edit: I'm using the default behavior of pyCharm.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz I might just have to do all of this in the terminal... which sounds horrible lol.

Comment: How are you running your program? The Python that you're using doesn't have `bs4` installed but the for your Pycharm project (where you were able to import `bs4`) does. In order to run you're program you'll have to either launch it from the project's virtual environment (in the terminal where `import bs4` worked type `python name_of_your_file.py`) Or you'll need to install bs4 for the python that you're trying to use to run your program.

Comment: BTW, easy way to see where the heck is the python you are currently running in - `print(sys.executable)`